# Debugging Coffeescript inside a Ruby on Rails app with Intellij IDEA 14 (not RubyMine)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, intellij-idea

Could someone please point me in the right direction for working out how I could get debugging a RoR Coffescript with Intellij?

I tried this guide:
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/RUBYDEV/Debugging+CoffeeScript+Code
.. but when I run the server (debug mode) and the JavaScript debug configuration (also debug mode), no breakpoints are hit.

As I am running IntelliJ and not RubyMine, do I need to set up a File Watcher to transpiling CoffeeScript to JavaScript? I setup the file mapper and that created some coffee.js and .map files, but then I received errors indicating that my .map.js file was not found.

I'm a little confused.. :S .. any help would be much appreciated, as I'm a complete n00b to RoR/Coffeescript.

Thanks a lot!